# ESP32 keep rebooting with rosserial

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I try rosserial with ESP32 on Ubuntu20.04.

but, ESP32 keep rebooting when using rosserial.

The Error is

```
Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:10944
load:0x40080400,len:6388
entry 0x400806b4
assertion "Invalid mbox" failed: file "/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/api/tcpip.c", line 374, function: tcpip_send_msg_wait_sem
abort() was called at PC 0x400d556b on core 1

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40085050:0x3ffb1dd0 0x400852cd:0x3ffb1df0 0x400d556b:0x3ffb1e10 0x400ec99f:0x3ffb1e40 0x400ec439:0x3ffb1e70 0x400ec5ec:0x3ffb1e90 0x400e47d0:0x3ffb1ed0 0x400d26be:0x3ffb1ef0 0x400d20be:0x3ffb1f40 0x400d1c01:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d31ce:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400862de:0x3ffb1fd0
```

I don't know why this error.

The skech is below.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>


ros::NodeHandle  nh;

std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);

char hello[13] = "hello world!";

    void setup()
    {
      nh.initNode();
      nh.advertise(chatter);
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
      str_msg.data = hello;
      chatter.publish( &str_msg );
      nh.spinOnce();
      delay(1000);
    }
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394805/esp32-keep-rebooting-with-rosserial/) by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2022-01-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-22**:
Please take a look at this thread: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4807#issuecomment-782414911

It seems ESP32 is trying to connect to wifi. Let me know if the recommended change works to document as an answer

**Comment by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on 2022-01-22**:
Thank you for your reply. It worked well!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-22**:
Thank you for confirming. I documented for future users.

**Comment by [xaobahn](https://answers.ros.org/users/146992/xaobahn/) on 2023-04-29**:
i am trying to build a facial recognition trigger project with esp32cam but i keep getting this on the serial monitor arduino ide :
SOMEONE PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!

rst: 0xc (SW_CPU RESET), boot: 0x13 (SPI FAST FLASH BOOT) configsip: 0, SPIWP: Oxee
c1k_drv: 0x00, 9_drv: 0x00,d_drv: 0x00, c0_drv: 0x00,hd_drv: 0x00, wp_drv: 0x00
mode: DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018, len: 4
load:0x3fff001c, len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
Load: 0x40078000, 1en: 10944
load: 0x40080400, 1en: 6388
entry 0x40080664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer is based on this solution found [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4807#issuecomment-782414911) for future users.

The problem is caused by ROS looking for `wifi` connection over `serial`.

To solve, change `ros.h` in the library folder: `~/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h`

Original:

```
#if defined(ESP8266) or defined(ESP32) or defined(ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TCP)
  #include "ArduinoTcpHardware.h"
#else
  #include "ArduinoHardware.h"
#endif
```

Modified:

```
#if defined(ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TCP)
  #include "ArduinoTcpHardware.h"
#else
  #include "ArduinoHardware.h"
#endif
```

Also it's suggested to check baud rate.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on 2022-01-22**:
The baud rate is 57600.I cannot find how change this.
Also, the serial monitor of Arduino IDE works fine on Windows, but not on Ubuntu.
rosserial works on both.